# on child added not returning anything

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have a database that looks like this:

[image]

```
  /*
  formsById
    formId
      usersList
        userId
  */
```

What I want to do is return a reference of all the users (usersList) associated with a specific formId. Here is my method in my provider:

```
  // this returns a list of users (ref) of the current form
  getFormsUsersRef(formId): firebase.database.Reference {
    let formsRef = firebase.database().ref("formsById");
    return formsRef.child(formId).child("usersList");    
  }
```

And here is the code in my component:

```
  // list the forms
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.sharingProvider.getFormsUsersRef(this.formId).on('child_added', fuSnap => {
      // not returning anything
      console.log(fuSnap);
    });
  }
```

If I console log what the getFormsUsersRef is returning it is correct (it is a database reference), however my .on('child_added') is not returning anything at all.

I use this same methodology on a different dataset in this app and it works perfect, the only difference is that my userId's are stored as firebase uid values and not push keys?

Any help appreciated I have been stuck on this for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out I was referencing `formsById` not `formsByID` - its now working correctly.

```
getFormsUsersRef(formId): firebase.database.Reference {
    let formsRef = firebase.database().ref("formsByID");
    return formsRef.child(formId).child("usersList");    
  }
```